# Register EF Core using IDbContextFactory in ASP.NET Core Mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I've created a project `App.Data` that contains domain objects and a base class that implements `IDbContextFactory<T>` for creating a `DbContext`. The code is available [here](https://gist.github.com/joacar/60d6faa9e6e20ba3dfb64b207708f442).

Generating the migrations in a seperate assembly works well.

What I would like to utilize the context I've created in `App.Data.Sql` that is created via an `SqlDbContextFactory<MyAppDbContext>` when registering entity framework within asp.net mvc.

What I want to have is something like

```
services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer()
.AddDbContext(typeof(SqlDbContextFactory<MyAppDbContext>))
```

Registering it as a singleton doesn't work since when resolved complains about no provider has been configured.

```
services.AddSingleton<IDbContextFactory<..>, SqlDbContextFactory<..>>();
services.AddScoped<MyApp..>(p => p.GetRequiredService<IDb..>().Create());
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `.AddDbContext(typeof(...))` provide a factory method to create context:

```
services.AddTransient(provider =>
{
    //if needed: anything from DI
    var bar = provider.GetService<TBar>();

    //if needed: external captured variable
    doSomething(service);

    //explicit context creation
    return new FooDbContext(...);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since ef core 5 you can add `DbContextFactory` as singleton to services list using

```
services.AddDbContextFactory<SomeDbContext>(b =>
    b.UseSqlServer(@"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=Test"));
```

as shown in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/whatsnew#dbcontextfactory). This code also automaticly adds SomeDbContext as scoped to DI provider.

If you want to add custom implementation of `IDbContextFactory` that uses `DbContextOptions` make sure to add it to services list before DbContext itself, or DbContextOptions would be added to the DI provider as scoped and it would cause exception on app start as described in the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2oWz9JwDhgk).

```
services.AddSingleton<IDbContextFactory<..>, SqlDbContextFactory<..>>();
services.AddDbContext<MyAppDbContext>(options => ..);
```